# Is the `:~>` Identifier in Haskell "Proper"?

Tags: haskell

I've seen this operator used on Haskell blogs, but cannot find its source in Hoogle. Is the `:~>` operator a part of the language core? If so, what does it denote?

**EDIT:** It does appear to show up in a [Hayoo search](https://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/?query=%3A~%3E), but which one denotes the canonical usage?

Comment: Which blogs? It's not built in to the language but I've mainly seen it used for natural transformations.

Comment: Your question is misleading. The Hayoo results show `:~>` defined as a type, not a normal operator.

Comment: There is no "canonical" usage. It is a valid identifier for a type constructor that anyone can use, so it could be used for anything. The blog post should make it clear through context where the operator comes from and what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not part of the language core. If it exists at all, it is defined by user code, not the compiler or any of the libraries required by the standard. It is also not included in any of the libraries that ship with the major extant implementation, GHC.